# is there a way to get the 'read more' tag in a manual excerpt

Tags: posts

I figured out how to make a custom/manually created excerpt to show on our home site and if the post title is clicked, the full post shows.

I would like to include the READ MORE tag at the end of the excerpt that can also be clicked to show the full post.

I see how to use the READ MORE tag in the full post as an alternate way to create an excerpt, but I can't figure out how to add that tag to the end of my custom/manually created excerpt.

help!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Click on the add more icon in the toolbar
2. Enter it manually

   `<!--more-->`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, the toolbar appears to be applicable to the body of the post only, not to the Excerpt box below.  I was hopeful about your second idea and tried manually entering it at the end of the Excerpt text, but nothing changed.  No "more" or other clickable item appeared at the end of my Excerpt after I updated.

Comment: and I guess that makes sense in that I really don't have any "more" of the EXCERPT to be viewed, what I want is an obvious place for them to click and have it go to the POST.  If they click on the title the little hand appears indicating that they can click that title and get to the full POST.  A 'more' indicator would just make it more obvious.  appreciate any thoughts on how to reach my goal.

Comment: @vkj would you please tell me what theme are you using?

Comment: I am new to Wordpress, but in the upper lefthand corner when I am creating a new post is a box that says    THEMECO